# How to let Hermes to switch to other properties file rather the default one?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am building GWT app and I am using Hermes to manage the `constants` at Server side.

Here is what I did:

I created `MyConstantsWithLookup.properties` (default English version) & `MyConstantsWithLookup_de.properties` (German version) & `MyConstantsWithLookup.java` in client package

-MyConstantsWithLookup.properties has

id=1245

-MyConstantsWithLookup_de.properties has

id=4556


-MyConstantsWithLookup.java

```
public interface MyConstantsWithLookup extends ConstantsWithLookup {
   int id();
}
```

There is `Data.java` in Server package. `Data.java` has

```
public static int id(){
    try {
        MyConstantsWithLookup myConstantsWithLookup = Hermes.get(MyConstantsWithLookup.class, "");
        return myConstantsWithLookup.id();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Ok, it works fine if i open the page in English. Ex, `myDomain.com` it will show correctly the `id=1245`. However, if i open the page in German language `myDomain.com?locale=de` then it did not pick up the `id=4556` but still use the old id.

Did i do anything wrong here?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

found solution that is to use MyConstants

in client,

```
public interface MyConstants extends ConstantsWithLookup{
    String id();
}
```

MyConstants_de.properties

id=2121

MyConstants.properties

id=4545

In server

```
MyConstants myConstants = Hermes.get(MyConstants.class, "");
myConstants.id(); //will print id=4545


MyConstants myConstants = Hermes.get(MyConstants.class, "de");
myConstants.id(); //will print id=2121
```